# How can I simply turn value labels of a variable into a new column in R

Tags: r, label

Suppose I have a dataset like the one below. How can I create string variables that are equal to the value labels of the columns `partido`and `comision1` in the data below?

That is the original dataset:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    cues                           partido                            comision1
   <dbl>                         <dbl+lbl>                            <dbl+lbl>
 1    15                          5 [PRO]                           3 [Relaciones exteriores y culto]  
 2    48                          7 [Partido Socialista]           23 [Transportes]                    
 3    39                          2 [UCR]                           1 [Asuntos constitucionales]       
 4    37                          2 [UCR]                           9 [Previsión y seguridad social]   
 5    66                         34 [Frente Cívico-Partido Nuevo]  17 [Agricultura y ganadería]        
 6     8                         14 [Moviemiento Popular Neuquino] 24 [Economías y desarrollo integral]
 7    63                          2 [UCR]                           4 [Presupuesto y hacienda]         
 8    11                          3 [PJ]                            3 [Relaciones exteriores y culto]  
 9    59                          1 [Frente para la Victoria]      25 [Asuntos municipales]            
10     7                          2 [UCR]                           8 [Justicia]
```

The output I desire would be something like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    cues         partido       partido_label               comision1    comision1_label

 1    15         5               PRO                         3         Relaciones exteriores y culto  
 2    48         7           Partido Socialista              23        Transportes                    
 3    39         2                UCR                        1         Asuntos constitucionales      
 4    37         2                UCR                        9         Previsión y seguridad social   
 5    66         34        Frente Cívico-Partido Nuevo       17        Agricultura y ganadería        
 6     8         14         Moviemiento Popular Neuquino     24        Economías y desarrollo integral
 7    63         2                 UCR                       4         Presupuesto y hacienda]         
 8    11         3                 PJ                        3         Relaciones exteriores y culto  
 9    59         1            Frente para la Victoria        25        Asuntos municipales            
10     7         2                UCR                        8         Justicia
```

And here is the code to create the original dataset:

```
45, 4, 8, 46, 14, 59, 39, 50, 19, 51, 47, 28, 40, 7, 42, 35, 
23, 65, 9, 67, 3, 32, 20, 34, 16, 26, 13, 57, 1, 11, 5, 44, 56, 
63, 62, 55, 10, 6, 27, 61, 66, 37, 36), label = "Nº de cuestionario", format.spss = "F4.0"), 
    partido = structure(c(3, 1, 34, 1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 14, 2, 
    9, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 34, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 24, 5, 
    27, 3, 2, 3, 7, 37, 3, 13, 1, 9, 2, 34, 1, 1, 2, 2, 34, 34, 
    2, 30), label = "Partido político", format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 16L, labels = c(`Frente para la Victoria` = 1, 
    UCR = 2, PJ = 3, `Coalición Cívica` = 4, PRO = 5, `Frente Cívico y Social de Santiago del Estero` = 6, 
    `Partido Socialista` = 7, GEN = 9, `Nuevo Encuentro` = 11, 
    `Proyecto Sur` = 13, `Moviemiento Popular Neuquino` = 14, 
    `Demócrata Mendoza` = 17, `Libres del Sur` = 19, `Renovador de Salta` = 20, 
    `Partido Federal Fueguino` = 23, `Salta Somos Todos` = 24, 
    `Demócrata Progresista` = 25, `Movimiento Popular Fuegino` = 27, 
    MIJD = 28, `Unión para Todos` = 30, `Frente Cívico-Partido Nuevo` = 34, 
    `Partido Bloquista de San Juan` = 35, `Partido de la Concertación-Forja` = 36, 
    `Unión Celeste y Blanca` = 37, `PJ Disidente` = 38, `Partido Renovador de la Concordia` = 39
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    comision1 = structure(c(4, 5, 4, 5, 11, 1, 3, 9, 27, 24, 
    1, 1, 25, 1, 4, 4, 10, 1, 27, 4, 8, 5, 12, 7, 31, 33, 3, 
    40, 15, 46, 3, 8, 10, 14, 46, 8, 3, 24, 38, 26, 4, 31, 2, 
    3, 30, 66, 13, 17, 9, 13), label = "Comisión que Ud. integra 1", format.spss = "F2.0", display_width = 12L, labels = c(`Asuntos constitucionales` = 1, 
    `Legislación general` = 2, `Relaciones exteriores y culto` = 3, 
    `Presupuesto y hacienda` = 4, Educación = 5, `Ciencia y Tecnología` = 6, 
    Cultura = 7, Justicia = 8, `Previsión y seguridad social` = 9, 
    `Acción social y salud pública` = 10, `Familia, mujer, niñez y adolescencia` = 11, 
    `Tercera edad` = 12, `Legislación penal` = 13, `Legislación del trabajo` = 14, 
    `Defensa nacional` = 15, `Obras públicas` = 16, `Agricultura y ganadería` = 17, 
    Finanzas = 18, Industria = 19, Comercio = 20, `Energía y combustible` = 21, 
    `Comunicaciones e informática` = 22, Transportes = 23, `Economías y desarrollo integral` = 24, 
    `Asuntos municipales` = 25, `Intereses marítimos, fluviales, pesqueros y portuarios` = 26, 
    `Vivienda y ordenamiento urbano` = 27, `Peticiones, poderes y reglamento` = 28, 
    `Juicio político` = 29, `Recursos naturales y conservación del ambiente humano` = 30, 
    Turismo = 31, Economía = 32, Minería = 33, `Prevneción de adicciones y control del narcotráfico` = 34, 
    `Análisis y seguimiento de normas tributarias y previs.` = 35, 
    `Población y desarrollo humano` = 36, Deportes = 37, `Derechos humanos y garantías` = 38, 
    `Asuntos cooperativos, mutuales y de org. no gubernamentales` = 39, 
    MERCOSUR = 40, `Pequeñas y medianas empresas` = 41, `Defensa del consumidor, del usuario y de la competencia` = 42, 
    `Seguridad interior` = 43, `Libertad de expresión` = 44, 
    Discapacidad = 45, `E. de modernización del funcionamiento del parlamento` = 46, 
    `E. Mixta revisora de cuentas` = 47, `E. Administradora de la biblioteca del congreso de la Nacioón` = 48, 
    `Bicameral de fiscalización de los Org. y activ. de inteligencia` = 49, 
    `Bicameral de seguimiento de facultades delegadas el P.E.N.` = 50, 
    `E. Parlamentaria conjunta argentino-chilena Ley 23172` = 51, 
    `Bicameral asesora de la federación argentina de municipios` = 52, 
    `Bicameral de la defensoría del pueblo` = 53, `E. Seg. de los emprendimientos hidroelectricos de Yacyretá, Corpus` = 54, 
    `Paritaria Permanente Ley 24.600` = 55, `Reforma del Estado y seguimiento de las privatizaciones` = 56, 
    `Bicameral negociaciones agrícolas internacionales` = 57, 
    `Seguimiento de obras para el aprov. integral del río bermejo` = 58, 
    `Bicameral permanente de trámite legislativo. Ley 26.122` = 59, 
    `Mixta unicameral del observatorio parlamentario sobre las malvinas` = 60, 
    `Bicameral de conmemoración de los bicentenarios` = 61, `Bicameral de control de los fondos de la seguridad social` = 62, 
    `Bicameral de seguimiento y coordinación para la confección del digesto juridico` = 63, 
    `Bicameral Investigadora/P. irregularidades/decla. juradas` = 64, 
    `Ciudad de Buenos Aires` = 65, `Promoción y seguimiento de la comunicación audiovisual` = 66, 
    `Bicameral Especial Ley 26.519` = 67, `Bicameral para la Reforma del código civil y comercial` = 68, 
    `Grupo de amistad con Ecuador` = 69, `Grupo de Amistad con UNESCO` = 70, 
    `Frente Parlamentario contra el Hambre` = 71, `Grupo de amistad con Italia` = 72, 
    `Grupo de amistad con Bolivia` = 73, Inseguridad = 74, `Problema fuera de campaña` = 75, 
    `Crisis institucional` = 76, `Grupo de amistad con Perú` = 77, 
    `Grupo de amistad con Vietnam` = 78, Etnias = 79, `Grupo de amistad con Canadá` = 80, 
    `Grupo de amistad con México` = 81, `Crisis internacional del capitalismo` = 82, 
    Corrupción = 83), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply the function `as_label` to multiple columns using `across`. You can also adjust their names with `.names` parameter.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  mutate(across(c(partido, comision1), 
         sjlabelled::as_label, .names = '{col}_label'))

# A tibble: 50 x 5
#    cues              partido                comision1 partido_label       comision1_label         
#   <dbl>            <dbl+lbl>                <dbl+lbl> <fct>               <fct>                   
# 1    29  3 [PJ]               4 [Presupuesto y hacie… PJ                  Presupuesto y hacienda  
# 2    52  1 [Frente para la …  5 [Educación]           Frente para la Vic… Educación               
# 3    60 34 [Frente Cívico-P…  4 [Presupuesto y hacie… Frente Cívico-Part… Presupuesto y hacienda  
# 4    68  1 [Frente para la …  5 [Educación]           Frente para la Vic… Educación               
# 5    49  3 [PJ]              11 [Familia, mujer, niñ… PJ                  Familia, mujer, niñez y…
# 6    58  2 [UCR]              1 [Asuntos constitucio… UCR                 Asuntos constitucionales
# 7    15  5 [PRO]              3 [Relaciones exterior… PRO                 Relaciones exteriores y…
# 8    45  3 [PJ]               9 [Previsión y segurid… PJ                  Previsión y seguridad s…
# 9     4  5 [PRO]             27 [Vivienda y ordenami… PRO                 Vivienda y ordenamiento…
#10     8 14 [Moviemiento Pop… 24 [Economías y desarro… Moviemiento Popula… Economías y desarrollo …
```

Comment: Great . I believe I can use dplyr "select" functions for that, such as "starts_with", right?

Comment: Yes, you can select all the tidyselect helper functions like `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `matches` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use dplyr and tidyr:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    partido = gsub('[]]', '', partido),
    comision1 = gsub('[]]', '', comision1)
  ) %>% 
  separate(
    col = partido, into = c('partido', 'partido_label'), sep='[[]'
  ) %>% 
  separate(
    col = comision1, into = c('comision1', 'comision1_label'), sep='[[]'
  )

df

#   cues partido      partido_label comision1               comision1_label
# 1   15      5                 PRO        3  Relaciones exteriores y culto
# 2   48      7  Partido Socialista       23                    Transportes
```

Say you have multiple columns, you may want something less hard-coded:

```
df <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=!cues,
    names_to='key',
    values_to='value'
  ) %>% 
  mutate(value=gsub('[]]', '', value)) %>% 
  separate(col='value', into=c('value', 'label'), sep='[[]') %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=key, values_from=c(value, label), names_glue='{key}_{.value}') %>% 
  as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df

#   cues partido_value comision1_value      partido_label               comision1_label
# 1   15            5               3                 PRO Relaciones exteriores y culto
# 2   48            7              23  Partido Socialista                   Transportes
```

The dataframe I tested on:

```
df <- data.frame(
  cues = c(15, 48),
  partido = c("5 [PRO]", "7 [Partido Socialista]"),
  comision1 = c("3 [Relaciones exteriores y culto]", "23 [Transportes]"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought. I was looking for solutions with packages such as `sjlabelled` or `labelled` but the solution was just in a simple conversion:

`test$partido_label <- as_label(test$partido)` and  `test$comision1_label <- as_label(test$comision1)`

Still would like to know how to easily do that for many variables at once. Maybe with `dplyr`.